# How should be a labelled image for semantic segmentation?

Tags: rgb, file-extension, grayscale, labeling, semantic-segmentation

As I understand from the below explanation, there will be two types of images for semantic segmentation which are inputs and masks. Mask images are the images that contain a **'label' in pixel value which could be some integer (0 for ROAD, 1 for TREE or (100,100,100) for ROAD (0,255,0) for TREE)**.

> Semantic segmentation describes the process of associating **each pixel of an image with a class label**, (such as flower, person, road, sky, ocean, or car).
>   https://se.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/semantic-segmentation-basics.html

According to my research, there are lots of types of labelled images for semantic segmentation. Along with the different extensions(.png .jpg .gif .bmp...), some of them are **RGB labelled (3-channel)** images and some are **GRAY (1-channel)** images. Below, there are two examples to explain this situation better.

1. RGB labelled with the extension '.png'

   > https://github.com/divamgupta/image-segmentation-keras#user-content-preparing-the-data-for-training
2. GRAY scale labelled with the extension '.gif'

   > https://www.kaggle.com/kmader/vgg16-u-net-on-carvana/#data

If my image has labelled as GRAY scale, I basically make it RGB by copying each value of this GRAY channel for 3 RGB channel. Just the opposite, by averaging the RGB channels, I can make the labelled image as GRAY scale. What is the difference? Which one is more suitable for which task (binary segmentation or sth else)?

In my case, I have **4 classes** and try to do multiclass semantic segmentation. [I've already labelled about 600 images on DataTurks](https://dataturks.com/projects/safakakinci17/TPT%20Dataset). That means, I just have the object's polygons, and I have to make my labelled image on my own. For now, **the extension of my input images and the mask images are '.jpg' and '.png' respectively.** How should I label my images along with the which extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save the mask as grayscale png images with the values being one of 0,1,2,3(since you have 4 classes) at each location corresponding to the class(tree, bush etc.) of the pixel values in the input images.

You can verify that the mask image is generated correctly by doing this.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
lbl_img = '<path_to_mask_image>'
mask = cv2.imread(lbl_img, 0)
print(np.unique(mask))
```

> [0 1 2 3]  # this will vary based on number of classes present in mask image